# Maximum Likelihood Estimator - Covariance Squared Exponential Matlab

Tags: maximum-likelihood, matlab, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process, hyperparameter

Following the Rasmussen&Williams Gpml Machine Learning book i'm trying to implement my gaussian process in matlab, avoiding to use other existing toolbox or complex pre-assembled functions, but now i'm stuck with the minimization of the negative log marginal likelihood in order to estimate the hyperparameters of my noisy *covariance function* and i'm not sure of it. In particular i used the *Squared Exponential* in the form:

```
Kxx = sf^2*exp(-0.5*(squareform(pdist(x)).^2)/ell^2)+(sn)^2*eye(Ntr,Ntr);
```

where ***sf*** is the signal standard deviation, ***ell*** the charactersitic length scale, ***sn*** the noise standard deviation and ***Ntr*** the length of the training input data ***x***. Is there any difference with expressing it in the form:

[image]

The negative log marginal likelihood is:

```
neglogml=0.5*ytr'*inv(Kxx)*ytr+0.5*log(det(Kxx))+(Ntr/2)*log(2*pi);
```

where ***ytr*** is the training noisy targets vector. Comparing it with that one obtained using Rasmussen's Gpml Toolbox the result is the same.

To optimize the parameters i need to evaluate the gradient of the *negative log marginal likelihood*. The partial derivatives are expressed by Rasmussen as:

[image]

and in my code, i.e. deriving for ***sf***, i obtain:

```
Kxxdsf=2*sf*exp(-(0.5*squareform(pdist(x)).^2)/ell^2);
nlmldsf=0.5*trace((inv(Kxx)*ytr*((inv(Kxx)*ytr)')-inv(Kxx))*Kxxdsf);
```

but the result is completely different (and wrong). I don't know where the problem is, maybe is related with logarithm or the matrix derivatives or computationl precision, but i can't see it.

Thank you in advance for helping!!

---

The problem were the hyperparamters considered, since often GP libraries use the logarithmic notation as explained here:

http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/

and here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030534/gradients-of-marginal-likelihood-of-gaussian-process-with-squared-exponential-co